# Showing $(p⟹q) ∨ (p⟹r) = p⟹(q∨r)$ are logically equivalent

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I need help proving, using laws of propositional logic that $(p⟹q) ∨ (p⟹r) = p⟹(q∨r)$. I'm not sure which laws I need to use to prove their equivalence. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use equiv between $a \to b$ and $\lnot a \lor b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

**Implication**

$P \rightarrow Q \Leftrightarrow \neg P \lor Q$

**Commutation**

$P \lor Q \Leftrightarrow Q \lor P$

**Association**

$P \lor (Q \lor R) \Leftrightarrow (P \lor Q) \lor R$

**Idempotence**

$P \lor P \Leftrightarrow P$